# django-filter for django rest frameworks

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am hoping there is a solution for my issue. I am trying to produce a call to a url in javascript from a path that looks like this: 
  /api/vendor_filter/?city=&zipCode=29615&dateServing=04%2F21%2F2018

I have set the filter of the call to call data from date and zip code.

What I am hoping to achieve is because this call already populates the date as current date and zip code from a registered device zip code that the zip code in this case 29615 actually pulls a range from 29601, 29627 so that any zip code in that range is retrieved.

This would be the same as stating list(range(29601,29627+1)) so that the user zip code pulls all zip code items in the database in that range.

The zip code could be as above or it could be 68011 in which case I would want a range of (67998, 68024) so regardless of the users zip code in the call the zip code is represented in the middle of the range,

Comment: some code please?

Comment: my question does this logic occur in serializers https://github.com/chucklapress/WhereTheTruckDev/blob/master/truckapi/serializers.py  or filters https://github.com/chucklapress/WhereTheTruckDev/blob/master/truckapi/filters.py

Answer (score 0):

Change your filter by this:

```
class VendorFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    zipCode = django_filters.NumericRangeFilter(queryset=VendorListing.objects.all())    

    class Meta:
        model = VendorListing
        fields = ['dateServing','city', 'zipCode']
```

You can use the filters from django_filters app. Read the [docs](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filters.html#filters)

Comment: I have corrected the VendorFilter and have read the documentation on Django-filters for NumericRange, which will require an adjustment to VendorListing model, Is this where the range logic has got to be implemented? , my original inquiry referenced the need for a range of data GET from a url request so if x = zipCode then all zipCode in range of x-8, x+8 are valid data. I am already capable of producing x from my call.  also if modification to data model is needed is there a better way to produce the range with a different data object.

Comment: actually modifying the model and utilizing Postgres NumericRange in the zipCode field is the way to make this work.